# How to create a (unknown) number of ArrayLists within an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem that I'm trying to Solve. I want to create an ArrayList of unknown number of elements, and in that ArrayList place other ArrayLists. For example: A hospital queue, and within this queue I want to have different queues based in the priority of the patient.

```
System.out.println("whats the maximum priority?");
int maxPriority = Scan.nextInt();

//Trying to create a new ArrayList in every ArrayList index.
for(int k=0; k<maxPriority;k++){
    queues[k] = new Arraylist();
}

//trying to create a "patient"-object with a name and priority
public static patient(String name, int priority){
    this.name=name;
    this.priority=priority;
}       
// trying to get the priority of a patient//
public static getPriority(){
    return priority;
}
// Trying to add the patient last in the correct "priority queue"

public static placePatient()){
    queues.add(patient.getPriority)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For having an ArrayList within an ArrayList, just do:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>();
```

That'll give you an ArrayList of ArrayLists of type Type. You can then just add ArrayList's to `list` as you would add to an ArrayList normally. You don't have to know the number of elements an ArrayList will hold in advance.

Comment: hank's for reply ! So if i type in this code. The program nows that this is an arraylist that contains Arraylists. So in this place if I write list.add(4) it ads a new list on index 4 ?? What about if I want to "find" the correct arrayList and then add a object to that arraylist ? Once again, thanks

Comment: Try it and see. list.add(4) will give you an error, as "4" is not an ArrayList. You can add an ArrayList with list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()) for example. You can add to a specific index of the ArrayList with list.add(elem,index). Take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E). The API doc explains the get() method which you want as well.